# Application-layer Secrets in Google Kubernates is not supporting Asymmetric keys

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-kms

I have created a RSA key (Asymmetric Key) in Google KMS. while trying to use it in GKE using Application-layer Secrets. the asymmetric keys are not getting loaded.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQILq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Kubernetes requires AES encryption. This is a symmetric encryption algorithm.

[Symmetric-key algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm)

Encryption keys have a purpose. Common types are **ASYMMETRIC_DECRYPT** and **ENCRYPT_DECRYPT**.

[KMS: Key purposes and algorithms](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/algorithms)

RSA keypairs provide asymmetric encryption which is not supported.

[Public-key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)

[Encrypt secrets at the application layer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/encrypting-secrets)

Typically RSA keys are used to exchange information (secrets, random numbers, etc) that is used to generate a symmetric encryption key. Encryption using RSA keys is expensive in CPU time, encryption using symmetric keys is very fast in comparison.

Comment: how can I retrieve the  RSA key from google KMS ? I have deployed the springboot service to GKE. while running the application in local I'm able to get the keyring by setting 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS' env variable.

Comment: @Vikas Do not ask new questions in the comment section. Instead, create a new question. don't forget to accept answers that help you. That way a question does not remain open forever.